# How to include files in an already created ZIP file using FileOpenPicker

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to add multiple files to an already created ZIP file using [PickMultipleFilesAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.pickmultiplefilesasync). I previously created the ZIP file I want to access in the same code using `FilesavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()` method. The app is running on Windows 10 Pro version 1803 in Laptop PC, and I used Visual Studio Community 2017 to create it.

The problem I get is that, after following steps described in the [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) MSDN page, I get a *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\'User'\Downloads{ZIP file}' is denied.'*

I created ZIP file and tried to add new files using this code:

```
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
 {
  // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
  CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
  try
   {
    Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
     {
       // This line works fine, file is added
       archive.CreateEntryFromFile(path_to_another_file, file_name_in_ZIP);
       //....
       var dialog = new MessageDialog("Do you want to add more files to ZIP?");
       //... (dialog configuration for Yes/No options)
       var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
       if(result.Label == "Yes")
        {
         Debug.WriteLine("Yes option was selected!");
         // Include additional files
         var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
         openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
         openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
         IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> addedFiles = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

         if (addedFiles.Count > 0)
          {
           // Application now has read/write access to the picked file(s)
           foreach (StorageFile addedFile in addedFiles)
            {
             Debug.WriteLine(addedFile.Path); // No problem here
             // I get the UnauthorizedAccessException here:
             archive.CreateEntryFromFile(addedFile.Path, @"additional files/" + addedFile.Name);
             }
          }
          else
          {
           // Update log file
           globalLog += GetTime() + "No additional files";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I already added `<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>` to appxmanifest just in case, but as I had access to selected files using FileOpenPicker I think that is not the problem.

As I created the ZIP file within this code I should still have access to it, right? I suspect that FileOpenPicker somehow "closes" access to ZIP file in order to give access to files to be added, or that MessageDialog prevents of accessing the ZIP file I created after I called showAsync().

Is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying?

**EDIT**: I can not access the file(s) I select using FileOpenPicker, despite I can show file name(s) in Debug console. ZIP file access is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution. As stated [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/zip-folder-and-its-content-in-windows-runtime-apps/), you can use a buffer to stream file contents to ZIP file, just replace:

```
// I get the UnauthorizedAccessException here:
archive.CreateEntryFromFile(addedFile.Path, @"additional files/" + addedFile.Name);
```

With:

```
ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(@"additional files/" + addedFile.Name);
byte[] buffer = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(addedFile));
using (Stream entryStream = readmeEntry.Open())
  {
    await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
```

That way, files are added and no `UnauthorizedAccessException` happens. Hope this helps anyone with the same problem!